# Ghost printer in print dialog box but not in printer control panel

Tags: printing

I have a weird problem with ghost printers that seems to be different from what other people have asked about.  In my case, the ghost printer appears only in the print dialog box.  The printer is just called "print" and won't accept jobs.  However, if I go to the printer control panel, everything looks normal.

[image]
[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: It's probably a found network printer. To prove it, disconnect from your network and see if it disappears... a reboot may be required. Also, look at http://localhost:631 to see if the printer shows up there.

Comment: When I disconnect the network, both my legitimate printer and the ghost printer disappear.  So now what?  There are no other printers on the network.

Comment: Your Epson printer is a wifi/network printer, yes? Then you'd expect it to disappear when you disconnect the network. The ghost printer disappearing means that somewhere on the network there's another printer-like device. Did the localhost link that I gave you show the ghost printer?

Comment: http://localhost:631/printers/ only shows the Epson printer.  However, the "find new printers" page shows this:

1) Virtual Braille BRF Printer (CUPS-BRF)
2) EPSON WF-3640 Series (EPSON WF-3640 Series)
3) EPSON WF-3640 Series (EPSON WF-3640 Series)
4) EPSON WF-3640 Series (EPSON WF-3640 Series (driverless))

Comment: Do you have a Braille printer?

Comment: No.  I searched for a way to remove it, but found nothing.  I'm assuming it's a built-in feature of CUPS or Ubuntu 19.10.